# Adding a middle node with linked lists

Tags: c++, linked-list

Hello I am creating a linked list program. I am getting an error below saying "expected type specifier before ""temp;". Any ideas, hints, clues? Thanks.

```
void add_middle_node(){

node *current;
current = start_ptr;

    if(current->nxt == NULL){

        add_node();
    }else{

        node *temp = new temp; // ERROR HERE

        get_details(temp);

        temp->nxt = current->nxt;

        current->nxt = temp;

        delete temp;

    }

};
```

Answer (score 2):

`new` operator expects a type and you're giving it a variable. Change it to `new node`.

Comment: I'm also somewhat confused by the body of the code, which assigns `current->next` to point to temp then deletes `temp`.

Comment: Of course , it is also incorrect because `current->next` points to the now deleted location I.e. It'd a dangling pointer. Also `current->next` before assignment was pointing to some non-null node which is lost (and was not deleted) thereby leading to a memory leak too. So yes, `temp` shouldn't be deleted here.

Comment: Yes. It is a memory leak. The value inserted is always 18 and creates an infinite loop. The pointers are messed up. Thank You. I have no idea why I put the delete temp in there.